# How do I rename a field of a document before publishing the reactive cursor to client?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe

For example, currently I have a `Message` document with `{_id: "abcdefgh", content: "Hey!"}`. Before the client receiving the document via pubsub, I would like to transform

```
{_id: "abcdefgh", content: "Hey!"} to {messageId: "abcdefgh", content: "Hey!"}
```

so that client could see **messageId** rather than **_id**. How can I do it in Meteor? Thanks!

p.s. I guess this is similar to [Mongoose's virtual attributes](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html)

Comment: of course, if you are OK with doing the transform on the client itself, you can always just use a transform argument to the `find` call on the client.

Comment: @ChristianFritz Hi Christian. I'm using a 3rd-party DDP client ([Meteor-ios](https://github.com/martijnwalraven/meteor-ios)), so I can't do transform on the client-side. In addition, I'll need to publish a reactive cursor to the client.

Comment: Then please look at the answer in duplicate. It explains how you can do this on the server prior to publishing.